What is the default note number when load wav file into MIDISampler?
With AudioKit, I load a sample:
        let sampler: MIDISampler = MIDISampler()

        do {
            try pulseAudioFile = AVAudioFile(forReading: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "soundfx", withExtension: "wav")!)
            try sampler.loadAudioFiles([pulseAudioFile])
        } catch {
            log.fault("Unable to load sound: \(error)")
            fatalError("")
        }

        let track = sequencer.newTrack()!
        track.setLoopInfo(Duration(beats: 4), loopCount: 0)
        track.add(noteNumber: 69, velocity: 127, position: Duration(beats: 0), duration: Duration(beats: 1))
        track.add(noteNumber: 69, velocity: 127, position: Duration(beats: 1), duration: Duration(beats: 1))
        track.add(noteNumber: 69, velocity: 127, position: Duration(beats: 2), duration: Duration(beats: 1))
        track.add(noteNumber: 69, velocity: 127, position: Duration(beats: 3), duration: Duration(beats: 1))

        sequencer.setGlobalMIDIOutput(sampler.midiIn)

However when I play the sequence, the sound is somewhat different from the original sample.
I tried using different pitches from 69-80, but still it sounds somewhat different. I searched the docs but did not found the default note number when importing an audio file.
What is the default note number which will play the original pitch of the sample? Also, is there a way to just play the sample as is without altering the pitch?

Just a complete guess, but since 60 is middle C, I'd think that may be the default

@jnpdx Turns out you are correct, make it an answer if you like. Not sure why not 440 middle A but middle C. Missed that!

@soundflix Stumbled upon another answer making the same guess, then tested true.
